# Chrome reloading embedded SVG object when hiding and showing parent DIV container

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom, svg

I am using Adobe Edge Animate to do some CSS3 animations, and using a plugin that converts the SVG images to  tags so that the SVG elements are accessible via Javascript. The problem is, when one of the parent DIV containers is hidden and later re-shown, the embedded SVG image is reloaded losing any changes that have been made to it, such as fill colors of shapes, etc.

This also causes some stuttering in the animation when a new image is loaded, as it takes a small amount of time to reload the image.

This problem is not present in Firefox or IE. Is there any way to tell chrome to not re-load embedded images when hidden and shown?

Here is a link to the page in question: [Link](https://rackperformancetest.azurewebsites.net/rotationalTimer/rotationalTimer.html)

If you press the enter key, it triggers part of the animation. You can see after the rotation where it switches out the image and flashes. If you use the built in function via browser console called changeBladeColor() you can see how it resets any changed attributes. This function changes the fill colors of the shapes in the SVG.

Here is an example usage for testing:
changeBladeColor(1, '#ff0000');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to position the elements off the page. I had to re-do a lot of my animation, so keep this in mind when doing any projects where you need to display and hide objects (especially ones that may not appear to be doing so).